# Add animations and effects when div enters visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

I would like to have the text on my page jump / fade in just like at [mfpins.com](https://mfpins.com). I have looked into adding classes when a div is a certain distance from the top however, I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing this (Preferably with jQuery). Whether the effect takes place only the first time it scrolls into view or every time does not matter to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery plugin like [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/).

For example:

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementById('waypoint'),
    handler: function(direction) {
        console.log('Scrolled to waypoint!')
    }
})
```